# Polymorphic macros in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I am looking for a way to have a Jinja macro that calls different implementations depending on the type of object that is being passed. Basically, standard Python method polymorphism. Right now, I'm using an ugly workaround similar to this:

```
{% macro menuitem(obj) %}
  {% set type = obj.__class__.__name__ %}
  {% if type == "ImageMenuItem" %}
    {{ imagemenuitem(obj) }}
  {% elif type == "FoobarMenuItem" %}
    {{ foobarmenuitem(obj) }}
  {% else %}
    {{ textmenuitem(obj) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

In pure Python, one can muck around with the module environment, e.g. `globals()[x+'menuitem']`, which isn't pretty but works very well. I've tried something similar using the Jinja context, but the latter doesn't seem to contain the macro definitions.

What better ways are there to achieve what I'm seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now solved my problem similarly to how fabrizioM suggested, with one notable difference: Since the menu item presentation can (and most of the time, does) contain HTML, I don't want mess around with HTML markup directly in the `present` methods. So I ended up implementing the menu definitions in Python, the presentation in Jinja, with mutual recursion bridging the gap.

Different types of menu items are represented by different subclasses:

```
class MenuItem(object):
    def present(self, macromap):
        return macromap[type(self).__name__](self, macromap)

class TextLink(MenuItem):
    def __init__(self, url, text):
        self.url, self.text = url, text

class Section(MenuItem):
    def __init__(self, text, items):
        self.text, self.items = text, items

class ImageLink(MenuItem):
    ...
```

The `macromap` referenced above is a dict mapping the type of menu item to the macro implementing its represenation. It's all defined in Jinja:

```
{% macro TextLink(l, macromap) %}
  <a class="menuitem" href="{{l.url|escape}}">
    {{ l.text|escape }}
  </a>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro Section(s, macromap) %}
  <div class="heading">{{s.text}}</div>
  <ul class="items">
    {% for item in s.items %}
      <li>{{ item.present(macromap) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endmacro %}

{% set default_map = {'TextLink': TextLink, 'Section': Section, ...}
```

The actual menu definitions are cleanly expressed as trees of `MenuItem` subclasses:

```
main_menu = section("Main Menu", [
    section("Product Line 1", [
        TextLink("/products/...", "A product"),
        ...
    ]),
    section(...),
])
```

To kick off the presentation, a template has to call the top level section's `present` method, passing a macro map to specify how to present the menu, e.g. `main_menu.present(default_map)`. As can best be seen in the `Section` macro, menu items can then ask their children to present themselves, whose `present` method will call yet another Jinja macro, and so on, recursively.

Having to explicitly pass around the macro map is not very pretty, but it grants a valuable benefit: One can now easily render different representations of the menu data without touching the menu definitions at all. For example, macro maps may be defined to render the main website menu, or a variant for mobile devices (in case CSS doesn't suffice), or an XML sitemap, or even a plain text version. (We actually ended up using this system for the website menu and sitemap cases.)

Answer (score 7):

The essence of OOP: polymorphism.

```
Create a presentation Layer for your objects:

class MenuPresentation:
    def present(self):
        raise NotImplementedException()

class ImageMenuPresentation(MenuPresentation):
   def present(self):
       return "magic url "

class TextMenuPresentation(MenuPresentation):
   def present(self):
      return "- text value here"
```

And then will be just a matter of:

```
{% macro menuitem(obj) %}
  {{ obj.present() }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Polymorphism does indeed lend itself to this problem. However, the presentation has to contain HTML, which I'd really like to keep separated out into Jinja templates. Your suggestion provided the final clue I needed to solve the problem, though -- thanks a lot!